# Vanishing of Goldman bracket requires simple-closed representative?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, surfaces, curves

Let $\Sigma$ be a connected oriented surface, and $[-,-]\colon \Bbb Z\big[\widehat\pi(\Sigma)\big]\times Z\big[\widehat\pi(\Sigma)\big]\to Z\big[\widehat\pi(\Sigma)\big]$ be the Goldman Bracket. Note that Goldman Bracket is a bi-linear skew-symmetric map satisfying the Jacobi Identity. Here $\widehat\pi(\Sigma)$ is the set of all free homotopy classes of loops in $\Sigma$, and $Z\big[\widehat\pi(\Sigma)\big]$ denotes the free module of $\widehat\pi(\Sigma)$ over the ring of integers.

One of the exciting properties of the Goldman bracket is the following:

> **Theorem:** If $\alpha$ is a simple closed curve representing  $x\in
>  \widehat\pi(\Sigma)$, then, for $y\in \widehat \pi(\Sigma)$, $[x, y] =
>  0$ if and only if $y$ can be represented by a closed curve $\beta$
> such that $\beta\cap \alpha=\varnothing$.

Now, in practice, you can not always expect $x$ has a representation by a simple closed curve, but after a homotopy, we have a representation of $x$ by a self-transverse immersion $\Bbb S^1\to \Sigma$ without any triple point. So, my question is the following:

> To what extent can we relax the condition of having a simple-closed
> representative? For example, let's say $x$ has a representation by the
> figure-eight curve $\alpha$ but $x$ has no simple closed representative, then can we say that $[x, y] =  0$ if and only if
> $y$ can be represented by a closed curve $\beta$  such that
> $\beta\cap \alpha=\varnothing$

Comment: No, this is not true in general. According to Exercise 10 in http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~moira/papers/2015ChasThe_Goldman_bracket_and_the_intersection_of_curves_on_surfaces.pdf a counterexample is given by the bracket of (the free loops associated with) $ab$ and $aab$ where $a,b$ are the obvious generators of the fundamental group of a twice punctured disc (so the first one is indeed the figure eight you're talking about).

Comment: Even easier: if $\alpha$ is any free loop then obviously $[\alpha,\alpha]=0$. although in general there is no way to choose a representative $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\cap \alpha=\emptyset$.